# Javascript regex replace inserts extra slashes

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to clean up a file using JavaScript. The file contains lines of text like this:

```
a <- b + c / d;
```

I want to replace all `<-` with `=` when there is a string of non-whitespace on either side of the `<-`, separated by a single space. Pretty easy in theory:

```
line = "a <- b + c / d"
result = line.replace( /(\S+) <- (\S+)/, /$1 = $2/ )
```

The above code produces `/a = b/ + c / d` when run. However, conceptually, it should produce `a = b + c / d`. How can I use `$1`-style backreferences without allowing JavaScript the opportunity to insert slashes willy-nilly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a string for the second parameter:

`result = line.replace( /(\S+) <- (\S+)/, "$1 = $2" );`.

What is happening is the second parameter is being coerced from a `RegExp` to a `String` which adds the slashes in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

2nd parameter of replace is not regex but String.

You need to use it like this:

```
result  = line.replace( /(\S+) <- (\S+)/, '$1 = $2' );
```